# How to safely wash my computer with garden hose?

Tags: cleaning, technology

Theoretically, the only problem of water with electricity is with electricity. So, if I wash my motherboard, RAM, CPU and everything else, it should boot fine if I make sure that there are no traces of water, right? Any traces of water could make a short-circuit.

I know I should be careful with:

- Oil from the ventilation. If it's 'cleaned', won't work anymore.
- Any too tiny hole that might hold water.
- Impure water may leave traces of something on the computer parts.

Did I forget anything?

So, how could I do a saturday cleaning in my computer knowing that it will boot tomorow?

Comment: You've probably falsely assumed that if you unplug your computer there is no electricity. Components can store electricity, which introducing water to, could cause short circuits and permanent damage.

Comment: Is there a workaround for it?

Comment: The only one I can think of is to use pure water (it's not the water that conducts electricity, it's the impurities). But this certainly doesn't come out of your garden hose. Even then I'd probably not trust the water to be pure enough to try it.

Comment: Welcome to Lifehacks SE. This question has been closed because this does not need a life hack as defined in the [help]. As commented above, it is also not very safe for your computer to clean it wih a garden hose.

Comment: Your hypothesis ("the only problem is with electricity") is incorrect - you have forgotten one pretty important thing: corrosion. Tiny metal parts  will corrode quickly when exposed to water. Granted, not *every* part will degrade (some metals are less prone to corrosion than others), but enough of the system *will* to transform your computer into a very expensive doorstop.

Comment: Things with moving parts or any battery must not be wet.  Tap water can be used to clean but final rinse with purified water or isopropyl alcohol is a good idea.  Only do this if it was in a flood and you cannot afford to replace it.  Usually easier to replace.        http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/141293/cleaning-pcbs-using-water/141325#141325

Answer (score 2):

Generally, blowing dust out of a computer is enough to keep it satisfactorily clean. If you spill something that needs liquid to remove, use isopropyl alcohol. Apply with a cotton swab gently until clean. The do it again to get trace residue off. Leave it for two minutes, more than enough time for a small amount to evaporate, before turning the system on.